# Debugging PowerShell script

Tags: c#, debugging, powershell

I am interested in developing a C# application that processes data, and to aid in filtering the data I plan to expose part of the application as an interpreted script via PowerShell. I think I have a good grasp on how to accomplish that (*[How to run PowerShell scripts from C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C)*), but it would be extremely valuable to offer debugging capabilities like those offered in [PowerShell ISE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315244.aspx). Is there a way to attach ISE (or a similar debugger) to a PowerShell script that is being hosted within the C# program?

Part of the reasoning behind this is the flexibility that some of the components are fixed in nature, hence the compiled C# executable, but some of it needs to be easily altered at runtime. I envision a DataTable or List<> being passed from C# into PowerShell, with a similar return value from the script that would have parsed data.

Comment: Just to clarify, debugging in powershell isn't dependent on the ISE. The debugging commands are built into the language, ISE just provides a GUI drop down menu that essentially just executes those commands. So the answer to the question is: the debugger is already "attached"

Comment: I was not previously aware of this fact.  Looking around I do see that [PowerShell provides its own debugging facilities](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730925.aspx), and this is likely a good starting point.

Comment: True, but you cannot use these features in your C# application without implementing a debugger that utilizes them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way of attaching a debugger capable of debugging PowerShell to an arbitrary host process.

It is possible to implement your own debugger - the necessary hooks are public, but this is a non-trivial task - you would need to implement the UI - you call an api to set breakpoints, then PowerShell will call you when a breakpoint is hit, at which point you decide what to do (e.g. wait for the user to say "go" or "step".)

Comment: This changes in PS 5.0

Comment: Yes, the Enter-PSHostProcess cmdlet along with Get-Runspace and Debug-Runspace, new to V5, help here.

Answer (score 1):

@Jason Shirk is correct about the debugger. But instead of implementing your own you can use some existing. For example, a simple debugger implemented as a script included to the NuGet package [NuGetDebugTools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGetDebugTools). In spite of the name the debugger works with any host (in particular, the NuGet console does not have its own debugger implemented). Note that its UI is *very* minimalistic, somewhat similar to MS PS console debugger. But it is workable and it is better than no debugger at all.

I hope the tip may be useful for debugging or as a starting point for implementing your own. But it looks like you are actually looking for an external console-like window (not necessarily console based) related to the current PowerShell session/runspace, where you can explore exposed objects and change them. In the ideal world ISE could provide it, I think. But it currently does not.

Comment: Hi Roman, you really should indicate in your answer that you're the author of the package. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156186/193205